# wraping large markdown paragraphs with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, markdown

I'm trying to find and wrap big paragraphs (more than a certain number of characters) into a span. currently I'm doing this:

```
output.replace(/(\n{2}|^)([^\n{2}]{500,})(\n{2}|$)/mg, '$1<span class="warning-big-paragraph">$2</span>$3');
```

markdown paragraphs are separated via two newlines.

the problem is when I test it with sample data like this:

```
text text text text [500 other chars]

text text text text [300 other chars]
text text text text [300 other chars]
```

It does not wrap the second paragraph.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder type of element doesn't matter. I just want to add some background color for warning.

Comment: @ Arash: Then to avoid creating invalid documents, use `div`.

Comment: sorry for not being clear enough. Paragraphs in markdown are separated by **two** newlines. So last two lines belong to one paragraph.

Comment: @ Arash: Doh! I knew that... Sorry. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part `[^\n{2}]{500,}`, doesn't do what you think it does. It will match 500 or more of any character except new line, `{`, `2`, or `}` times. Try this:

```
var pattern = /(\n{2}|^)((?:[^\n]|[^\n]\n[^\n]){500,})(\n{2}|$)/mg
```

This will match a pair of new-line characters or the start of the string, followed by 500 or more non-newline characters or new-line characters not adjacent to any other new line characters, followed by a pair of new-line characters or the end of the string.

But there are still a few problems here:

1. It will not match the first paragraph if there's a single new line before it, or the last paragraph if there's a single new line after it.
2. It would require four newlines between two consecutive long paragraphs, because the previous match ends with two new lines and the next match begins with two new lines.

This pattern addresses these two issues:

```
var pattern = /(\n{2}|^\n|^)((?:[^\n]|[^\n]\n[^\n]){500,})(?=\n{2}|\n$|$)/mg
```

This will match a pair of new-line characters, the start of the string and a single new-line character, or the start of the string, followed by 500 or more non-newline characters or new-line characters not adjacent to any other new line characters, followed by a pair of new-line characters, a single new-line character and the end of the string, or the end of the string. The last part is a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), so it's not included as part of the match, meaning for two consecutive matches, it can be used as a condition of the previous match and part of the next match.

You can test it [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28%5Cn%7B2%7D%7C%5E%5Cn%7C%5E%29%28%28?%3a%5B%5E%5Cn%5D%7C%5B%5E%5Cn%5D%5Cn%5B%5E%5Cn%5D%29%7B10,%7D%29%28?=%5Cn%7B2%7D%7C%5Cn%24%7C%24%29&input=%0A12345%0A678901%0A%0A1234567890%0A%0Asome%20text%0A%0Asome%20text%0Asome%20text%0Asome%20text%0A%0Asome%20text%20some%20text%20some%20text%0A%0Asome%20text%0A%0A).

Comment: Thanks but I can't make it work. have a loot at [this regex test](http://scriptular.com/#%28\n{2}|^%29%28%28%3F%3A[^\n]|[^\n]\n[^\n]%29{10%2C}%29%28\n{2}|%24%29||||g||||[%2212345%22%2C%22678901%22%2C%22%22%2C%221234567890%22])

Comment: @ArashBadieModiri: Works for me: http://jsbin.com/ukisez/1 ([source](http://jsbin.com/ukisez/1/edit)).

Answer (score 1):

There's always the brute force approach:

```
output = output.split("\n\n").map(function(para) {
    return (para.length > 500
        ? ('<div class="warning-big-paragraph">' + para + '</div>')
        : para);
}).join("\n\n");
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/uceloy/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/uceloy/1/edit)

Note: That uses `Array#map` from ES5, which requires a "shim" for some browsers (notably IE8 and earlier). If you search for "ES5 shim" you'll find several options.

Or the boring old-fashioned way:

```
var paras;
var index;
var para;
paras = output.split("\n\n");
for (index = 0; index < paras.length; ++index) {
    para = paras[index];
    if (para.length > 500) {
        paras[index] = '<div class="warning-big-paragraph">' + para + '</div>';
    }
}
output = paras.join("\n\n");
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/uceloy/2) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/uceloy/2/edit)